# How to select the node with grand-grandchild node that has particular value

Tags: xpath, xquery

Hi I just want to get the Element A with value of "123abc" in it. I have tried both but failed.

> //Package/A[A/B/C/. = 123abc]
>
> //Package/A[contains(A/B/C,123abc)]

I want it to return this:

```
  <A>
    <System mtm="8742" os="Windows XP" oslang="en" />
    <System mtm="2055" os="Windows XP" oslang="jp" />
    <A>
       <B>
           <C>123abc</C>
           <C>789</C>
           <C>567</C>
       </B>
     </A>
    </A>
```

Sample xml to run query on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Database version="300">
<Package>  
<A>
    <System mtm="8742" os="Windows XP" oslang="en" />
    <System mtm="2055" os="Windows XP" oslang="jp" />
    <A>
       <B>
           <C>123abc</C>
           <C>789</C>
           <C>567</C>
       </B>
    </A>
</A>
</Package>
<Package>  
<A>
    <System mtm="8742" os="Windows XP" oslang="en" />
    <System mtm="2055" os="Windows XP" oslang="jp" />
    <A>
       <B>
           <C>efg123</C>
           <C>789</C>
           <C>567</C>
       </B>
    </A>
</A>
</Package>
</Database>
```

You can test your answer here: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Added the actual xml i am trying to process, but won't work could it be special characters escaped?

actual xml i am trying to process is below, i have tried

> //TableSection/SectionItem[SectionItem/Cell/. = "00-18-E7-17-48-64"]
>
> //TableSection/SectionItem[contains(SectionItem/Cell,"00-18-E7-17-48-64")]

```
      <TableSection name="SNMP Devices" IsTreeFormat="true">
       <SectionProperties>
        <Column id="1" Name="IP Address" />
        <Column id="2" Name="Description" />
       </SectionProperties>
       <SectionItem>
        <Cell columnid="1">
         192.168.99.54
        </Cell>
        <Cell columnid="2">
         WMI XScan
        </Cell>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          ScanType
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          WMIScan
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          Device description
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          WMI dscription
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          MACAddress
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          00-18-E7-17-48-64
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
       </SectionItem>
       <SectionItem>
        <Cell columnid="1">
         192.168.99.55
        </Cell>
        <Cell columnid="2">
         WMI XScan
        </Cell>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          ScanType
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          WMIScan
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          Device description
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          WMI dscription
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          MACAddress
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          90-2B-34-64-16-9D
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
       </SectionItem>
       <SectionItem>
        <Cell columnid="1">
         192.168.99.107
        </Cell>
        <Cell columnid="2">
         VMWare : &quot;navvms08.Crest.local&quot;
        </Cell>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          MACAddress
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          00-07-E9-0D-05-C5
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          Device identifier
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.4.1
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          Device name
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          &quot;navvms08.Crest.local&quot;
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
        <SectionItem>
         <Cell columnid="1">
          Device description
         </Cell>
         <Cell columnid="2">
          &quot;VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-1623387 VMware, Inc. x86_64&quot;
         </Cell>
        </SectionItem>
       </SectionItem>
      </TableSection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original sample you need to quote your comparison string. Both of these work:

```
//Package/A[A/B/C/. = "123abc"]

//Package/A[contains(A/B/C,"123abc")]
```

The query for the actual XML you're running against should be:

```
//TableSection/SectionItem[SectionItem/Cell[contains(.,"00-18-E7-17-48-64")]]
```

---

The problem with:

```
//TableSection/SectionItem[SectionItem/Cell/. = "00-18-E7-17-48-64"]
```

is that the text content must match exactly, while the XML has leading and trailing whitespace.

The problem with:

```
//TableSection/SectionItem[contains(SectionItem/Cell,"00-18-E7-17-48-64")]
```

is that `contains()` only looks in the first `SectionItem/Cell` within `//TableSection/SectionItem` instead of *any* `SectionItem/Cell` therein to find the text.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have added the actual xml that i am trying to process to the original question, because i am still not able to get the query to work. Much appreciate if anyone can sort this out for me, as i have spend hrs on this.

Answer (score 0):

For the first example, you have not quoted the string you are comparing against. Also you do not need the additional `/.` expressions as the node atomizaton rules will be applied for the string comparison anyway.

The XPath `//Package/A[A/B/C = "123abc"]` will suffice.

If you want to do a partial match against the text content of `C` then you could use `//Package/A[A/B/C/contains(., "123abc")]`. You do need the `.` in this as you want to find an `A` element that has a `C` grand-daughter element which contains the text `123abc`. The `.` refers to the current context, which here is an individual `C` element.
Otherwise, if you did `A/B/contains(C, "123abc")` you would get a type error as you have multiple `C` elements and `fn:contains` cannot operate on a sequence.

---

For the second example, the example without contains is a whitespace issue, you could fix this by using `contains`, however your contains tries to operate on a sequence. Instead you should rework it to something like this:

```
//TableSection/SectionItem[SectionItem/Cell/contains(., "00-18-E7-17-48-64")]
```