# In Playwright for Python, how do I use a QuerySelector to match partial text inside a tag?

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to match a H1 tag on a page that has several h1 tags using partial text.

For this example the text is "Your booking was"

```
<header data-v-20d51c72="" data-v-3cdc5826="" class="default__title">
   <h1 data-v-20d51c72="" data-v-3cdc5826="" class="default__title">Your booking was unsuccessful.</h1>
</header>
```

I can locate against the full text like this

```
 page.querySelector('//h1[normalize-space()="Your booking was unsuccessful."]')
```

I can also get a list of all h1 tags and then check the innerHTML for all

```
 [handle for handle in page.querySelectorAll('//h1') if handle.innerHTML().startswith('Your booking was')]
```

But this way, I can't wait for the handle to appear.

How can I write a selector so that I can match against a partial tag so that I can use `page.WaitForSelector()` on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a hint from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416426/how-to-select-the-node-with-grand-grandchild-node-that-has-particular-value/26421307#26421307) a working selector is

```
handle = page.querySelector('//h1[contains(., "Your booking was")]')
```

Where

```
print(handle.innerHTML())
```

prints 'Your booking was unsuccessful.'